# python parallel processing

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I am new to Python. I have 2000 files each about 100 MB. I have to read each of them and merge them into a big matrix (or table). Can I use parallel processing for this so that I can save some time? If yes, how? I tried searching and things seem very complicated. Currently, it takes about 8 hours to get this done serially. We have a really big server with one Tera Byte RAM and few hundred processors. How can I efficiently make use of this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Whether you can parallelize this depends on whether the merging phase is CPU-bound or I/O-bound, in addition to your hardware.

Comment: Just saying, Python probably isn't the best tool for this. Maybe there's more information that makes it a better fit, but something like C or C++ will probably be easier and more efficient and processing large amounts of data.

Comment: Is the merge operation something trivial/segmented, like concatenation?  Or something like a reads/op/write (sum, e.g.)?

Comment: @root45: It might not be as bad as you think. The asker talks about matrices, so it may be possible to use something like numpy to do the grunt work in compiled code, while controlling the process from Python.

Comment: what format is the file in? have you tried numpy.fromfile?

Comment: May be I think that you can make a matrix of filenames of 20*100
And then using processes or threads you can assign eachof them each row then I think it could work as I am also a beginner please correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make be able to preprocess the files in separate processes using the *[subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess)* module; however, if the final table is kept in memory, then that process will end up being you bottleneck.

There is another possible approach using shared memory with *[mmap](http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html#module-mmap)* objects.  Each subprocess can be responsible for loading the files into a subsection of the mapped memory.